# Dynamic Image Button Event handlers not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a dynamic table being build on page_load.

I put the table inside an update panel so that I could add rows dynamically without a full page postback.  Each row has 4 cells first 3 containing textboxes and the 4th cell being an image button that needs to delete the row.

However the image button to remove the row is posting back but not firing the event handler sub.

I set the table to a session variable for reloading on postbacks.

```
<%--Update Panel with Image Button to add row--%>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlHA" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" >
 <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAddHA" AlternateText="Add Row" ImageUrl="../images/plus_orange.png" style="width:17px; height:17px; cursor: hand;" runat="server" />
    <div style="height:100px; overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
        <span runat="server" id="spanTBL_HA" />
    </div>   
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on page.init if the pnl page is in postback then it recreates the span

```
    If pnlHA.Page.IsPostBack Then
        spanTBL_HA.Controls.Clear()
        spanTBL_HA.Controls.Add(CType(Session("tblHA"), Table))
    End If
```

Image button being added to table cell

```
img = New ImageButton

Session("tblHA_Counter") = CInt(Session("tblHA_Counter")) + 1

img.AlternateText = "Delete Row"
img.Attributes.Add("style", "height: 10px; width: 10px; cursor: hand;")
img.ImageUrl = "../images/minus_red.png"
img.ID = "img_" & CInt(Session("tblHA_Counter")).ToString
AddHandler img.Click, AddressOf imgRemove_Click
img.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")

tc.Attributes.Add("style", "width:35px")
tc.Controls.Add(img)
```

Click Event

```
Protected Sub imgRemove_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim img As ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)
    Dim delRow As TableRow = Nothing
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    For Each row As TableRow In CType(Session("tblHA"), Table).Rows
        If CType(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), ImageButton).UniqueID = img.UniqueID Then
            delRow = row
        End If
    Next

    If delRow IsNot Nothing Then
        CType(Session("tblHA"), Table).Rows.Remove(delRow)
    End If

    spanTBL_HA.Controls.Clear()
    spanTBL_HA.Controls.Add(CType(Session("tblHA"), Table))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls need to be recreated *every* time the page is created to allow ASP.NET to restore view state, postback data and event wireup to the dynamically created controls. So remember to recreate them on the postback as well.

Please check whether you are creating them on every post back.

Comment: The initial table is created on page_load and set to a session variable and then added to the span. During a postback on page_init I reset the span control to the session if its not nothing.. span_tblHA.Controls.Add(CType(Session("tblHA"), Table)).  Doesn't that meet the "recreated" requirements?